# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) in MaskRCNN

Tags: python, computer-vision, faster-rcnn

I am trying to train my own dataset with MaskRCNN, I got the code from https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN and I started training my dataset with this framework I got this error.

I tried training another dataset of some other person then the code was running fine but not in my case

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "farm.py", line 363, in <module>
>         train(model)
>     File "farm.py", line 183, in train
>         dataset_train.load_custom(args.dataset, "train")
>     File "farm.py", line 135, in load_custom
>         height, width = image.shape[:2]
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
> ```

Comment: `print(image.shape[:2])`

Answer (score 1):

1).  height, width = image.shape[:2]
  Here height and width are expecting 2 values and we are providing them only 1, in this condition, you will get Error given below:-
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
2). print the value of image.shape[0:2] to see the number of values.

```
print(image.shape[0:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

check `print(image.shape[0:2])`  You will get an idea where you are wrong.